# Moving list elements with a particular value to end of list

Tags: c++, list, sorting, stl

I have a list of strings and I am trying to bring all the strings with a particular value to the end of the list. In the code that I have written I am trying to use a functor and list sorting to bring all the strings equal to "Hello" to the end of the list.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

struct DescendingFunctor
{
private:
    string StructString;

public:
    DescendingFunctor(string S) : StructString(S) {}

    bool operator()(const string& LHS, const string& RHS)
    {
        return LHS > StructString;
    }
};

int main()
{
    list<string> s;
    s.push_back("C++");
    s.push_back("World");
    s.push_back("Hello");
    s.push_back("Hello");
    s.push_back("World");
    s.push_back("C++");

    DescendingFunctor d("Hello");
    s.sort(d);

    return 0;
}
```

However when I try to use this code, I get an invalid comparator error. I know that the source of this error is with the expression -

```
return LHS > StructString;
```

Because when I replace it with

```
return LHS > RHS;
```

The list is sorted in descending order. Is there any way I can use list::sort to bring all the strings equal to "Hello" to the end of the list? If not what would be a good way to achieve this?

Comment: In my understanding I am passing both LHS and RHS as arguments, but I am only using one of them. I assume my understanding is incorrect. Could you explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this logic

```
bool operator()(const string& LHS, const string& RHS)
{
    return LHS != StructString && RHS == StructString;
}
```

It gives you what you want.

You are getting invalid comparator error because for some two items `A` an `B` being compared the operator returns true saying that `A` **should precede** `B` at the same time saying that `B` **should precede** `A`. At the same time returning false does not mean that the second should precede first.

Anyway the same task can be done with lower time complexity which is `O(n)` instead of `O(n * log(n))`.

Answer (score 2):

For a number of reasons, you should prefer using [`std:partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) for this:

1. As you note (in the comment), you're only using one of the arguments to your binary predicate. This makes your binary predicate inconsistent - it doesn't really define the [relevant ordering](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html). Conversely, the predicate in `partition` is unary, and you can semantically use it exactly for what you want.
2. In terms of complexity, sorting is an overkill for what you need, as the complexity is *Θ(n log(n)*; conversely, the complexity of `partition` is linear.

Perhaps you can try something like this:

```
std::partition(
    std::begin(s),
    std::end(s),
    [](const string &w){return w != "hello";});
```

Comment: The actual problem I'm tackling requires me to use lists (my question is a simplification of the problem). While I see how partitions are a much better fit in this example, do you have any suggestions of how I could achieve my goal with lists?

Comment: @propeeper: `std::partition` only requires ForwardIterators, while `std::list` provides BidirectionalIterators, so it should partition a list without any problems.